The shortcut hint
Given a string and a char, add an underscore (_, which won't appear in the input) before any one instance of the char, case-insensitive; if the char never appears in the string, append the char to the end surrounded by ().

You can assume ASCII input, though the screenshot isn't.
Shortest code in each language wins.
Test cases
Search, S => _Search
Translate, N => Tra_nslate
Cut, X => Cut(X)
Snap 10th, 1 => Snap _10th
Snap 50th, 2 => Snap 50th(2)
Excavate, E => _Excavate or Excavat_e
Cut(X), ( => Cut_(X)
Cut(X), X => Cut(_X)
Cut(X), ) => Cut(X_)
Cut(X), V => Cut(X)(V)
Test, q => Test(q)
Test, ) => Test())

Notes

Test cases here don't necessarily match real hotkeys.
Should I add background?


Perhaps add a test case with more than one occurrence of the character, resulting in multiple _? Also, can _ itself be part of the input and/or the character?

Most environment use & instead, so they are &Search, or Cut (&X)

@tsh & is sth Cut(&X). "Add an underline(_, which won't appear in input) ".

Excavate, E => _Excavate invalidates an existing answer. Please clarify whether "any" is plural or singular here.

What char is possible for highlight. Consider add more testceses where the highlighted character is ], \​, ., ^, +, *, (, {, $,  .

@doubleunary There's no word anys so misunderstand make me add the expilict one

Great. "any: at least one; at least one kind of; some; a positive quantity of."; "used to refer to one or some of a thing or number of things, no matter how much or how many"

Is it guaranteed that the character is given in upper case?

"Should I add background?"  Yes.

Suggested to add space as the target character.

Perl 5 -pl, 30 bytes
$c=<>;s/\Q$c/_$c/i or$\="($c)"

Try it online!

Vyxal, 16 bytes
⇩$⇩₌ḟc[\_Ṁ|_⁰øb+

Try it Online!
Maybe something with assign and functions is shorter, but for now, insert works
Explained
⇩$⇩₌ḟc[\_Ṁ|_⁰øb+­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
⇩$⇩               # ‎⁡Push both inputs lowercased. Stack will be [haystack, needle]
   ₌ḟc            # ‎⁢Push haystack.find(needle), needle in haystack
      [           # ‎⁣If needle in haystack (i.e the character is in the string case-insensitive):
       \_Ṁ        # ‎⁤  Insert a "_" at the index (0-indexed)
          |       # ‎⁢⁡Otherwise:
           _      # ‎⁢⁢  Pop the index (which will be -1)
            ⁰øb   # ‎⁢⁣  Surround the character in ()
               +  # ‎⁢⁤  And append it to the sentence


Created with the help of Luminespire.

C (gcc), 71 70 bytes
i;f(s,c){printf(i?"%.*s_%s":"%.*s(%s)",i-s,s,i?:c,i=strcasestr(s,c));}

Try it online!

Python, 73 bytes
lambda s,c:[s[:(i:=s.lower().find(c.lower()))]+'_'+s[i:],s+f'({c})'][i<0]

Attempt This Online!
Ungolfed for better understanding:
def f(s,c):
 # case insensitive search, return index or -1 if not found
 i = s.lower().find(c.lower())
 # use the index to select the correct string
 # first option, selected if found, inserts a _ at position i
 return [s[:i]+'_'+s[i:], s+f'({c})'][i<0]

80 bytes using regexp

-3 bytes thanx to att
-6 bytes thanx to CursorCoercer

lambda s,c:(t:=re.sub(r'(?=\u%04X)'%ord(c),'_',s,1,2))+f'({c})'*(s==t)
import re

Attempt This Online!
Exploited regexp mechanics:

'\u%04X'%ord(c): Convert the character to a Unicode escape sequence to prevent special characters breaking the regexp
(?=x): Lookahead to match the position before x
re.IGNORECASE = 2: Flag to make matching case-insensitive

87 bytes using partition
def f(s,c):h,d,t=min(map(s.partition,(c*2).title()));return[s+f'({c})',h+'_'+d+t][d>'']

Attempt This Online!
89 bytes using recursion
f=lambda s,c,h='':s and(s[0]in(c*2).title()and(h+'_'+s)or f(s[1:],c,h+s[0]))or h+f'({c})'

Attempt This Online!

-3: re.I -> 2

Nice... unfortunately, if you search e.g. for the dot character, the regexp version fails, because it is not escaped.

81 byte regexp by using lookahead

80 byte regexp by using a unicode escape sequence instead of re.escape

Google Sheets, 68 bytes
=let(t,regexreplace(A1,"(?i)("&B1&")","_$1"),t&if(t=A1,"("&B1&")",))


The formula will "Add an underline before any instance of the char, case-insensitive", as specified, and thus adds multiple underscores when the character appears multiple times.
To only add an underscore before the first instance of the char, use this (74 bytes):
=let(t,regexreplace(A1,"(?i)("&B1&")(.*)","_$1$2"),t&if(t=A1,"("&B1&")",))


Japt, 21 bytes
There's gotta be a better way.
i'_Uv bVv¹r"_$""({V})

Try it
i'_Uv bVv¹r"_$""({V})     :Implicit input of strings U & V
i'_                       :Insert "_" in U at index
   Uv                     :  Lowercase U
      b                   :  First 0-based index of, or -1 if not present
       Vv                 :    Lowercase V
         ¹                :End insert
          r               :Replace
           "_$"           :  RegEx /_$/
               "({V})     :  With V interpolated between parentheses


JavaScript (Node.js), 75 bytes
c=>g=s=>s?s[U='toUpperCase']()[0]==c[U]()?'_'+s:s[0]+g(s.slice(1)):`(${c})`

Try it online!

65 by regex

JavaScript (Node.js), 49 bytes
s=>c=>`${s}(${c})`.replace(/((.).*).\2.$/i,'_$1')

Try it online!
From Arnauld's deleted answer
-7B from tsh

.replace(/((.).*).\2.$/i,'_$1')

Charcoal, 24 bytes
≔⌕↥θ↥ηζ¿⊕ζ«…θζ_✂θζ»«θ(η)

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
≔⌕↥θ↥ηζ

Case-insensitively find the position of the accelerator in the string.
¿⊕ζ«

If the accelerator was found, then...
…θζ_✂θζ

Output the first half of the string, then a _, then the second half.
»«θ(η)

Otherwise output the string and the accelerator surrounded with ()s.
Alternative solution, also 24 bytes:
≔⌕↥θ↥ηζ⭆θ⁺…_⁼κζι¿‹ζ⁰⪫()η

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
≔⌕↥θ↥ηζ

Case-insensitively find the position of the accelerator in the string.
⭆θ⁺…_⁼κζι

Output the string with the match (if any) preceded with _.
¿‹ζ⁰⪫()η

If there was no match than output the accelerator surrounded with ()s.

Retina 0.8.2, 26 bytes
i`((.).*)¶\2
_$1
¶(.)
($1)

Try it online! Takes input on separate lines but link is to test suite that splits on ,  for convenience. Explanation:
i`((.).*)¶\2
_$1

If a matching character in the string can be found for the accelerator, precede the match with _ and delete the accelerator.
¶(.)
($1)

If the accelerator has not been deleted then wrap it in ()s and join it to the end of the string.

J, 54 bytes
(F{.[),](')',~'(',[)`('_',])@.(*@#@])[}.~F=:i.&tolower

Try it online!
I tried for hours to make this feel good. My second attempt, which tried to avoid the F=: assignment, was much longer, even after much golfing:
;(,')',~'(',])&>/@[`(]({.,'_',}.)0>@{[)@.(#@(0>@{[)*@-])i.&tolower
;(,')',~'(',])&>/@[`(]({.,'_',}.)F)@.(#@(F=:0>@{[)*@-])i.&tolower
,(}:,')',~'(',{:)@[`(]({.,'_',}.)}:@[)@.(#@}:@[*@-])i.&tolower
i.&tolower(}:,')',~'(',{:)@]`(({.,'_',}.)}:@])@.(#@}:@]*@-[),
i.&tolower(}:,')',~'(',{:)@]`([({.,'_',}.)}:@])@.(#@}:@]>[),
i.&tolower(}:,')',~'(',{:)@]`([({.,'_',}.)}:@])@.(<#@}:@]),

Agenda is probably not the way to go here, maybe there's more bytes to be saved by a completely different approach.

05AB1E, 22 bytes
DlIlk©diD®è'_ì®ǝë"ÿ(ÿ)

Case-insensitive replacing isn't really 05AB1E's strong suit..
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
D                 # Duplicate the first (implicit) input-string
 l                # Convert the copy to lowercase
  Il              # Push the second input-character, as lowercase as well
    k             # Get the first 0-based index of this character in the string
                  # (or -1 if none were present)
     ©            # Store this index in variable `®` (without popping)
      di          # If the index is non-negative (aka, not -1):
        D         #  Duplicate the string on the stack again
         ®è       #  Pop and get the character at index `®`
           '_ì   '#  Prepend a "_"
              ®ǝ  #  Insert it back at index `®`
       ë          # Else:
        "ÿ(ÿ)    "#  Push string "ÿ(ÿ)", where the first `ÿ` is the string on the stack,
                  #  and the second `ÿ` is the (implicit) second input-character
                  # (after which the result is output implicitly)


Uiua, 28 bytes
◌⍥:⊃∈(⊂⊂⊙@_⊃↙↘⊗:)⊃∩⌵⟜$"_(_)"

Try it: Uiua pad
⊃∩⌵⟜$"_(_)" puts on the stack the two uppercased inputs, the first input, and "first(second)".
(⊂⊂⊙@_⊃↙↘⊗:) first index of letter, fork split drop, join with underscore between.
◌⍥:⊃∈ check membership of the (both uppercased previously) letter in the string, flip the two stack items that many times, and pop. (Basically: if member, pop the parenthesis thing, otherwise pop the underscore thing)

Perl, 43 bytes
$c=pop;$_=pop;s/\Q$c/_$&/i or$_.="($c)";say


The arguments have to be separated by a space
If one argument contains sapce, it have to be surrounded by quote
For example: Snap 10th, 1 should be passed as "Snap 10th" 1

$c=pop;         # retrieve the 2nd argument, the character 
$_=pop;         # retrieve the 1st argument, the string
s/\Q$c/_$&/i      # find the character and add _ before, \Q escapes the character in order to work with .
 or             # OR, if it is not found
$_.="($c)";     # concat the character suround by parenthesis
say             # print the modified string


This fails if the input character is ..

@Xcali: You're right, fixed.

JavaScript (Node.js) , 79 bytes
x=>([a,b]=x.split`, `,V=a.indexOf(b))<0?a+` (${b})`:a.slice(0,V)+'_'+a.slice(V)

Try it online!

You can input 2 args so it's 63; and V<0 can be replaced with ~V

but it fails case-insensitivity

Java (JDK), 93 bytes
(s,c)->s.matches("(?i).*\\Q"+c+"\\E.*")?s.replaceFirst("(?i)(\\Q"+c+"\\E)","_$1"):s+"("+c+")"

Try it online!

Errors if c is (

Bash, 99 bytes
for((i=0;i<${#1};i++));{ b=${1:i:1};[[ ${b,} =~ ${2,} ]]&&{ echo ${1/$b/_$b};exit;};}
echo "$1($2)"

Try it online!
Bash, 101 bytes With special characters support
for((i=0;i<${#1};i++));{ b=${1:i:1};[[ ${b,} =~ "${2,}" ]]&&{ echo ${1/$b/_$b};exit;};}
echo "$1($2)"

Try it online!

Nice! Fails for certain special characters though, e.g. $

AWK, 39 bytes
$1~$2&&sub($2,"_"$2)||$0=$1"($2)",$0=$1

This only seems to work on gawk, whereas mawk and nawk will throw you an error. Also, it runs on TIO, but prints out gibberish :-p
